# How make correctly replace?

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

Good day.

*in define.php we have rows:*

```
define('test_word','word for test define');
define('test_word2','word for test define2');
define('test_word3','word for test define3');
define('test_word4','word for test define4');
```

*etc.*

*in functions.php we have functions, for example:*

```
function word($word){
echo $word;
}
```

*and we have index.php*:

```
<div>{test word}</div>
<div>{test word}</div>
```

Where `word` - it any word or function, for example it can be `test_word` or word('word for test function') etc.

*for example code page index.php can be:*

```
<div>{test test_word}</div>
<div>{test word('word for test function')}</div>
```

In result we would like get content index.php with replaced values between `{test` and `}`.

For example if we have index.php with code:

```
<div>{test test_word}</div>
<div>{test word('word for test function')}</div>
```

In result we should get:

```
<div>word for test define</div>
<div>word for test function</div>
```

We can get content on next step:

*File test.php*

```
<?php
include "define.php";
require_once("functions.php");

$content = file_get_content("index.php");
//BUT what make next?
?>
```

*Tell me please what me need next and how correctly replace rows in my example?*

Comment: I'm lost. Could you explain that better? (especially why are you doing that and not via `str_replace()` or `strtr()` with static replacements list)

Comment: @AlmaDo it need make with `str_replace() or strtr()` in file `test.php` after row `$content = file_get_content("index.php");` but i'm not know how make it... i can not use static replacements list becose  i would like get universal solution for such cases becouse if each function will be add me need read also file with static replacements list and it not good... tell me please what you not understand in my question?

Comment: Why don't you use a template parser like Smarty or Twig?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good with regular expressions, so hopefully someone will improve upon this, but here is what I've come up with to satisfy what you're asking

```
$content = file_get_content("index.php");
$lines = explode("\n",$content);
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $variableFound = preg_match('/{test (\w+)}/',$line, $variables);
    $functionFound = preg_match('/{test (\w+)\(\'([\w ]+)\'\)}/',$line, $function);

    if($functionFound == 1)
        $function[1]($function[2]);
    elseif($variableFound == 1)
        echo $variables[1];
}
```

There is a limitation here though, that is you can only have one function call or one variable per line in your index.php file, so that might be a deal breaker, but you can just keep breaking the line down until you don't find anymore matches if that's an issue. This should get you started anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. I have provided explanation in the comments of the code wherever necessary.

This is the code for test.php-

```
<?php
include "define.php";
require_once("functions.php");
$content = file_get_contents("index.php");

/*
    Splitting the input, so that each line can be individually processed.
*/
$lines = explode("\r\n",$content);
$prefix = "test";
$regex = "/<div>{".$prefix."[ ]([a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:[ ]*\((?:.*?)?\))?)}<\/div>/";

foreach($lines as $line){
    echo "<div>";
    //Check if the input matches the regex pattern.
    if(preg_match_all($regex, $line, $matches)){
        /*
            The constant or the function-name is captured in group 2(index 1).
        */
        if(count($matches > 1)){
            //
            $const_func = $matches[1][0];
            //Checking if the constant is defined.
            if (defined($const_func)){
                echo constant($const_func);
            }else{
                //Check if the variable matches function syntax.
                if(preg_match_all("/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[ ]*\((.*?)?\)/", $const_func, $func_matches)){
                    $func_name = $func_matches[1][0];
                    $func_args_arr = sanitise_args(explode(",",$func_matches[2][0]));
                    //check if  the function is defined.
                    if(is_callable($func_name)){
                        call_user_func_array($func_name, $func_args_arr);
                    }else{
                        echo "Function not defined";
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "Invalid String";
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo "No match";
        }
    }else{
        echo "No match";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}

//A function to clean up the arguments.
function sanitise_args($arr){
    return array_map(function($v){return trim($v," '\t\n\r\0\x0B");},$arr);
}
?>
```

OUTPUT -

```
-----------file - define.php        (I've added an extra constant).

define('test_word','word for test define');
define('test_word2','word for test define2');
define('test_word3','word for test define3');
define('test_word4','word for test define4');
define('random_const', 'this is a random constant');

-----------file - functions.php     (I've added an extra function).

function word($word){
    print_r($word);
}
function sentence($word1, $word2){
    echo "$word1 and $word2 are used in this sentence.";
}


-----------file - index.php

<div>{test test_word}</div>
<div>{test test_word2}</div>
<div>{test random_const}</div>
<div>{test word('word for test function')}</div>
<div>{test sentence('enter','sandman')}</div>

-----------OUTPUT

<div>word for test define</div>
<div>word for test define2</div>
<div>this is a random constant</div>
<div>word for test function</div>
<div>enter and sandman are used in this sentence.</div>
```

What the code basically does is this-

- Split the file contents line-wise.
- Check if each line follows the set-pattern
- Get the constant or the function string.
- Check if the string is defined as a constant and if it is, output
  constant value.
- If it's not a constant, then it will either be a function or an
  invalid string.
- Check if the string matches the structure of a function.
- Split the function name and it's arguments.
- Check if the function is callable.If not, then it's undefined.
- If it's callable, call the function.